# How do I access the $locationProvider to configure it?

Tags: angularjs

What is the correct way to get the `$locationProvider` configuration parameters from a service / controller ? When doing a simple dependency injection with `function ( $locationProvider )`, I get the following error :

```
Unknown Provider : $locationProviderProvider <- $locationProvider <- myCtrl
```

Comment: I doubt it is injectable, since it is used for injecting an instance of $location service. There is getter/setter hash([hash]); method in $location service, it may help you for doing whatever you want. If it does not you should explain your intention for using $locationProvider's hashPrefix.

Comment: @CemOzer I'm doing a Reverse Url service (ie. generating an url from a route name), so I need to know how is configured the location service to be fully generic.

Comment: I cannot say i understand your intention on "generating an url from a route name", can you give a example case study.

Comment: Hm, something like this : $routeProvider.when('/:user/profile', { name: 'profile_url' }) /// <a href="{{ 'profile_url' | reverse:{ user: 'jean' } }}"></a>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I also got this error.

You're allowed to inject a `$location` into a controller, but  *not* a `$locationProvider`.

Instead, the `$locationProvider` can be injected into a `config` method:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($location) {
  $location.path("/some/path");
});
```

And since I made this additional mistake: it's not just that you should add an `app.config` bit, but also remember to remove `$locationProvider` from the controller arguments, or you'll keep getting this error.

If I understand things correctly, provider configuration happens during the configuration phase of the app lifecycle, as opposed to the run phase. Thus this separation. [You can read a bit more about these phases here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

I suspect that the reason for the error message is that when you inject `$foo` into a controller, it looks for a `$fooProvider`. Thus when we injected a `$locationProvider`, it looked for a `$locationProviderProvider`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I believe your title edit changed the question itself - I was asking how to configure the $location configuration at runtime, from a controller. The actual answer is that it's not possible.

Comment: Mael - ugh.  If you can't configure it in the controller, then how the heck are you supposed to do it?  (boy, I hate Angular...)