# AngularJS Unknown Provider: $locationProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack to the run the AngularJS application. My project is first built using webserver, gulp and livereload. Now while trying to build the project using webpack, I'm facing the below error in the console.

Error: Unknown provider: $locationProvider

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#25abb7">

<!-- font awesome from BootstrapCDN -->
<link href="assets/fa/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- compiled JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/keycloak/keycloak.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script> 



<div>
  <div ui-view="header"></div>
  <div ui-view="main"></div>
  <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Your code is strange, as you have your `bundle.js` ABOVE angularjs from CDN and angular-ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dependency Injection is done right.

Maybe it cannot find the provider because it is minified?

Can you copy your js code ?

Here is an example of how you inject it:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    //Do something with the locationProvider

}]);
```

I think this link might solve your issue [How do I access the $locationProvider to configure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892246/how-do-i-access-the-locationprovider-to-configure-it)

Comment: I have injected already but the same issue.                                                                              module.config(['$httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider', function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider ) {  
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');  
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/' );   
}]);